# How can I exit from a loop from a method?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a basic username and password creator for a project. While creating the username part, I was trying to break a loop statement from a method. Can it be done with the way I wrote the code?

I have created the code as below.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Username {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        accepted=false;
        while(!accepted) {
            System.out.println("Please create a suitable Nickname:");
            nickName(scan.next());
        }
    }

    public static void nickName(String name) {
        if (name.length()<8) {
            System.out.println("Nickname must be at least 8 Characters");
        } else if (name.length()>=16) {
            System.out.println("Nickname must be lesser than 16 Characters");
        } else if (name.contains("é")|| name.contains("*")|| name.contains("!")|| name.contains("$")) {
            System.out.println("Nickname should not contain (é,*,!,$) characters");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your Nickname: " + name + " is created");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: you need to update the value of 'accepted'. How else do you plan this on working? Have your  validation method return a boolean and re-assing accepted to that value.

Comment: I was trying to update the accepted value, but couldn't solve it. Thanks to the answer it is solved 

Answer (score 1):

Make `nickName` returns `true`/`false` if valid/not valid and set `accepted` to the returned value:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Username {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        accepted=false;
        while(!accepted) {
        System.out.println("Please create a suitable Nickname:");
        accepted = nickName(scan.next());
        }
    }
    public static boolean nickName(String name) {
        if (name.length()<8) {
            System.out.println("Nickname must be at least 8 Characters");
            return false;
        } else if (name.length()>=16) {
            System.out.println("Nickname must be lesser than 16 Characters");
            return false;
        } else if (name.contains("é")|| name.contains("*")|| name.contains("!")|| name.contains("$")) {
            System.out.println("Nickname should not contain (é,*,!,$) characters");
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your Nickname: " + name + " is created");
            return true;

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I was trying to create the return methods but couldn't formulate it.